# Save and load a Tensorflow model after training to predict new input

Tags: tensorflow, save, restore

Hello tensorflow Community.
i am new in tesnsorflow , i use tensorflow to classify images now i work with cats_dogs dataset.
i want to save my model after training,and load it in an other program to predict other input
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have not read even basic tutorials where this is explained in details.

Comment: i read tensorflow tutorials ,, and now my model is succuessfuly  saved ,, but to restore this model, do i need to recreate my computation graph before restore it ???